# Using a LINQ method with 2 Where clauses will not work for some reason

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a LINQ Method like this:

```
List<string> paths = db.ClientStatement_Inventory
                     .Where(x => x.statementYear == year)
                     .Select(c => c.statementPath).ToList();
```

The above method works perfectly and it puts the statement path into "paths" from the database depending on what year is checked.

For some reason when I add another where clause it will not contact the db and put the any of the statement paths into the variable "paths".

Here is my second linq method:

```
List<string> paths = db.ClientStatement_Inventory
                     .Where(x => x.statementYear == year)
                     .Where(x => x.statementMonth == month)
                     .Select(c => c.statementPath).ToList();
```

I am setting the year and month to a string like so:

```
for (int y = 0; y < years.Length; y++)
            {
                var year = "";
                if (years.ToString() != "")
                {
                    year = years[y];
                }
```

I have tried multiple different ways to do the two where clauses from different stack overflow questions but nothing seems to work. I am not getting any error message when debugging and stepping through my code.

Comment: "it will not contact the db" Are you 100% sure that's the case? You've set up a profiler and confirmed you see the one query and not the other?

Comment: Have you tried to fetch by month only? Are there records in database for this combination of year and month? How month is declared? There should be nothing wrong with multiple where clauses.

Comment: @aquinas The only reason i say " its not contacting the db with two where clauses" is because when i have one where clause it take 30+ seconds to grab the files and put them into "path".  When i add an additional where clause or && it goes right over the linq method in a split second and "paths" is set to count 0.

Comment: Well, that indicates to me that you don't have any rows that match that year and month rather than it isn't going to the database. What happens if you say x.statementMonth != month?

Comment: It doesn't mean that it have not hit the database. Use db profiler to see if it actually hits.

Comment: @New_Coder did you hit DB profiler? Interesting to see SQL from call with 1 and 2 `where`. Also we still don't know which DB engine youre using. Also, would be useful to know data types of `x.statementYear` and `x.statementMonth` and corresponding table columns

Comment: @New_Coder any news?

Answer (score 1):

If this was LINQ to objects, this would work. But because this is Entity Framework... you never know. Your SQL is not built correctly. This is it. Do this

```
.Where(x => x.statementYear == year && x.statementMonth == month)
```

Comment: I have tried that from another persons question. It's so weird. When i just do one where clause and step through my code once i hit this linq method it will stop for 20 seconds because its grabbing a lot of files and putting them into "paths". But once i add another where or && once it gets to the linq method it hits it and then goes right past it in a second. So i know it didn't do any querying to the database and all of the files are not on "path".

Comment: That doesn't seem correct. `.Where` returns a `IQueryable<T>`, which can be chained together like the OP is doing.

Comment: @New_Coder I can't talk about performance of your DB, This is different subject. But I can tell you that, depending on SQL EF provider (I worked with Oracle EF, MySql EF and Sql Server EF providers), the output SQL can be correct or not correct. Sometimes LINQ is converted into correct SQL by 2 of these providers but not third one. So I need to try different LINQ ways until all 3 providers do correct job.

Comment: @T.S. that is so weird.. So are you basically saying its kinda a hit or miss?

Comment: @aquinas I've seen this on many occasions when EF provider, which is responsible for SQL generation is not doing a great job building queries. Often you can fix that by changing `Where` in your code

Comment: @New_Coder yes. In fact, you can intercept the query. In your context you can make query write to output or even trace it in SQL Profiler if you use Sql Server

Comment: @T.S. okay so thats two of you on this question that told me to use SQL Profiler .. never used it but i am going to look into that right now.

Comment: @T.S. Fair enough. I think I've only used the SQL Server EF provider. All I can say is, if there is an EF provider that is not letting you chain together `.Where`s, it is *fundamentally* broken.

Comment: All due respect, but your answer is incorrect. *That doesn't seem correct* was a polite understatement that IMO should have prompted you to remove or improve your answer.

Comment: @GertArnold I would wait for OP to bring back the news before removing the answer. There is obvious difference in execution